# How do I find the correct distance spacing for distributing equidistant points on a sphere of a given diameter?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

How do I find the correct distance spacing for distributing equidistant points on a sphere of a given diameter?

I don't need to fill the sphere with equidistant points.  I just need less than a hemisphere.  Lets say around 100 points packed together at equidistant distances between 0.1 inches and 0.2 inches on a sphere with a diameter of 1.25 inches.  The spacing cannot vary more than 0.001".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem#Configurations_of_smallest_known_energy

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358046/is-the-fibonacci-lattice-the-very-best-way-to-evenly-distribute-n-points-on-a-sp

Answer (score 3):

For some ready-to-use code (with a demo, see below), you can use the [Fibonacci algorithm](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/41142). (Click on the $</>$ sign at the top of that page to see the code.)

[image]
<sub>demo by Jim Bumgardner</sub>

*Fibonacci algorithm:* A fast method of producing an arbitrary number of equally distributed points around a sphere. This is accomplished by drawing a fibonacci spiral (similar to sunflower seed pattern) that maintains constant surface area.

Comment: I have seen all those approaches.  I am not a mathematician.  I am a design engineer.  I cannot see how those approaches can generate actual numbers for like what I have in my question.

Comment: @Jason: The code produces actual numbers - how else could it plot them?  If you have questions about how to implement the algorithm, some other site would be better - this site is about research mathematics and people generally write for an audience of mathematicians.